# replicating <li> dots when using <div> tags

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML output:

some text

some text

some text

As you can see, I'm using this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
<ul>
```

The problem is that I want to insert a div after the second `<li>` element and it's invalid HTML to put divs inside lists. So I want to change my HTML to this:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="MyListElement">some text</div>
  <div class="MyListElement">some text</div>
  <div class="SomeOtherClass">A bunch of nested divs here</div>
  <div class="MyListElement">some text</div>
</div>
```

This will work but the problem is that it won't display the dot character that goes in front of `<li>` elements.

What should I change/add to the `<div>` based HTML so that I have large dot characters like in the ones that are displayed in the `<li>` based HTML.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you put your `div` *into* the second `li` tag?

Comment: So, what's the problem that this solution is intended to solve?

Comment: @DavidThomas: it's intented to display a dot before "some text"

Comment: No, that's the problem you're asking about which is a result of the solution you've chosen for a previous problem. This problem is a result of *that*, *first*, problem; that's the one I'm interested in. Please see '[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add `display: list-item` for div's inner `.Container`:

```
div.Container > div
{
   display: list-item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I want to insert a div after the second `<li>`
>   element and it's invalid HTML to put divs inside lists.

You can put `div`s *into* `li` tags:

```
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>
      some text
      <div class="level-1-div">
          hello
          <div class="level-2-div">real</div>
      </div>
      <div class="level-1-div">world</div>
  </li>
  <li>some text</li>
<ul>
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCUJh/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will work (all divs with class `MyListElement` will be preceded with a bullet.)

```
div.Container > div.MyListElement {
    display: list-item;
    margin-left: 1.3em;
    list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mDABD/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class=libox>this should have a bullet before it</div>
<div class=libox>so should this</div>

<style>

.libox {
margin-top: 4pt;
margin-bottom: 6pt;
margin-left: 1em;
display: list-item;
list-style: disc;
margin-right: 0pt;
text-indent 0pt;
font-family: Arial, "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do with a div that you can't do with a list-item. If you have a true list, keep it as a list (if just for semantics/readability), and don't insert the item as a div -- rather, insert it as another list-item and style it appropriately -- you can just turn off the dot for that one item, if that's your goal:

```
<li id='aNonBulletedItem'>Some text </li>
```

CSS:

```
#aNonBulletedItem{list-style:none}
```